# Get starting with Zend Lucene

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

I decided to use Zend Lucene to search for keywords into my .pdf and .doc files, but really need a push, the documentation available from the official site is higher a bit from a big newbie like me.

May I find a volunteer that give me first steps to get started, just  three or four first steps will be highly appreciated!

For information: I'm using standard PHP and Netbeans 6.8 as an IDE, zero experience with Zend Framework.

Accept my Regards!
Dany90.

Comment: Which part of the Zend Documentation is complicated for you? Where does it hang you could need a push?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how this works out for you... the last time I used Zend_Lucene... searching was very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include just the parts of the framework you need. You wont need to use the entire stack.

The best place to get started is here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

Comment: The minimal download package will be fine. It will include the entire framework, but you only need to include the parts you want to use in your code.

Comment: Thanks datasage, I suppose that it's integration with Netbeans is simple!